How to make recaptcha v2 square selection open on top of the recaptcha element?

On lower resolutions like mobile devices, the square selection opens left which makes it unusable and a bad user experience.
I tried setting data-size to compact so the recaptcha doesn't go out of sight on smaller phone screens. It doesn't make the selection screen to open on top of the recaptcha though.
Any suggestions to improve user experience?
